# exception while login with facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

**while I am using login with facebook I am getting this type of exception.please resolve my problem.**

exeption is:FacebookActivity could not be started. Please make sure you added FacebookActivity to the AndroidManifest.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line in your `AndroidManifest`.xml file

```
<application
    ---------------------
    your application themes & label
    --------------------->
    <activity android:name=".FacebookActivity"
               android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this line to your manifest file.

```
  <activity> 

   ...
  </activity>
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
        android:exported="true" />

</application>
```